# What means the "average Bytes" metric in logfiles?

Tags: googlebot, logging, apache-log-files

I'm currently studying the logfiles - namely those from Googlebot access. I realized, that the *average Bytes* metric is in the majority of cases (urls) 10-20% of the page size. Many questions were rising:

- What means the *average Bytes* metric? How can it be interpreted, in general, and in relation to the Googlebot behavior?
- Is *average Bytes* anyhow related to the `HTTP request` size?
- What means high and low size of *average Bytes* regarding Googlebot behavior?
- Is it something saying about what portion of the page was read by Googlebot?

Comment: Are you using a tool to study your log files?? Cheers!!

Comment: some tools. But this metric is coming directly from server.

Comment: Okay. I did not recognize the term average bytes and just wanted to clarify if someone else was to try and answer your question. As for myself, while I do look at my log files directly by editing them, I only look for abuses. It has been a long time since I delve into the details so I simply do not remember them. Cheers!!

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this "average Bytes" metric? (Please show a snippet from your logs.) And what format string are you using to generate your Apache logs?

Comment: @MrWhite nothing special - as expected, just a number with a decimal delimiter. can't nothing say about format string - i just get a gz-ed file.

Comment: "can't nothing say about format string - i just get a gz-ed file." - So how do you know this value represents "_average_ Bytes"? The [_log format_](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) determines the values that are logged. "Average Bytes" isn't something that Apache normally logs and I don't see it as something that can be logged in the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html). (?)

Comment: @MrWhite hmm, client delivered a CSV with headings - AverageBytes was one of headings. I tested some of according values - their size was like GZipped source code.

Comment: "a CSV with headings" - that doesn't sound like an Apache log file. An Apache log file does not have "headings" and is not normally a CSV file. _Aside:_ "average", by definition, is a statistical _calculation_ based on multiple values (ie. _requests_ in this case) - this isn't something that Apache (mod_log_config) does. Apache logs information about the current request only (quickly). Any (slow) calculations are usually reported using (3rd party) log analysers later. Apache can log various metrics regarding the size (bytes) of the request/response - but none of these are an "average". (?)